# cloudbees database dump

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

How i can export the mysql database out of [cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.Com) ?

I'd like to use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) or comparable command, but my database is hosted by cloudbees so I can't ssh to the mysql host to run such a command.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your database from outside the Cloudbees network, using mysql connection parameters you can grab from [https://run.cloudbees.com/a/{{accountId}}#db-manage](https://run.cloudbees.com/a/%7B%7BaccountId%7D%7D#db-manage).

Use your favorite mysql tools to export and manage your database, like [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.fr/products/workbench/).